# how can i fix this error while configuring CMake in a VTK project

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, vtk

i get the following error message while configuring CMake

****CMake Error at CMake/vtkCompilerChecks.cmake:22 (message):
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 or later is required.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:53 (include)****

i don't know where is the problem in the  CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As the error message suggests... you should install Visual Studio 2015 or later. Have you done this?

Comment: i have the Visual Studio 2013 installed yet !  should i change the version??

Comment: If you are using a current version of VTK that may be a requirement. I would trust the error message. Kitware most likely put it in because of an incompatibility with old versions of Visual Studio probably because of the new c++11, c++14, c++17 releases.

Comment: Okay i Will try a later version of VS

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you have to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 or later and try again.